# change element in array based on position given java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to change values in array based on their positions given:

```
int[] array = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

int[] position = {5 , 2 , 3};
```

positions I want to change = 5th ,2nd ,3rd

change value to 3;

result = 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? try `for (int p : position) array[p] = 3;`

Comment: please delete your two "answers" and accept the posted answer by Арсен Мирзаян.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i : position){
  array[i] = 3;
}
```